# Issue connecting to SQL Server 2012 Express edition using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having an issue while connecting to SQL Server 2012 Express edition running on my PC using Oracle SQL Developer v4.1. I downloaded JDBC 3rd-party database driver. I have the TCP/IP enabled and am using port 1433. My SQL Server browser is also enabled. I am getting this error message:

> Status : Failure -The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://my-pc\SQL2012:port:1433/dbname;instance=SQL2012' is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, still having issue, yes i did change the instance name to SQL2012 during my installation

Comment: Did anybody run into an issue like this before, can anyone has any documentation or link about this issues.

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.I am using the following:

Comment: Any help would be much appreciated.I am using the following values in oracle sql developer new connection window :- host: pcname\SQL2012, in the port section: port:1433/db;instance=SQL2012, i am still getting the error saying Status : Failure -Test failed: The syntax of the connection URL 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcname\SQL2012:port:1433/db;instance=SQL2012/' is invalid. Just wondering what is the reason error is saying , the syntax is invalid. TIA!

Comment: finally, i was able to fix the problem, i am putting it here for anybody who may run into similar issue. host: localhost;port:1433/TestDB;instance=SQLEXPRESS